# Failed to execute script in CMD

Tags: java, cmd, executable

I have an .exe file on MyDocuments folder. I can't seem to run the program in the command prompt if I run `C:\User\User\MyDocuments\Sample.exe`. This gives me an error `Failed to execute script`.

But when I'll have the command prompt opened on the MyDocuments folder and only run `Sample.exe`, the programs runs perfectly.

What I want to do with this is I want to have a java program and execute `Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("C:\\User\\User\\MyDocuments\\Sample.exe");` and it will give me the `Failed to execute script` error.

Any I ideas what I missed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by [Application will not launch from command line full path, but will after CDing to directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18366882/application-will-not-launch-from-command-line-full-path-but-will-after-cding-to) I would make sure your executable does not depend on the current working directory.

Try Running:

```
Environment.CurrentDirectory = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;
```

before your try and execute your executable.

Comment: Would this be on Java or on CMD?

Comment: Powershell. Sorry just read the java program part. Try `System.setProperty("user.dir", "/foo/bar");` instead. Where `user.dir` needs to be there and change `/foo/bar` respectivly

Comment: Tried that. `String y = System.getProperty("user.dir");
                    Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(y + "\\Sample.exe");` it worked. Thanks